# What Type of map is this?

Tags: web-mapping, cartography

Looking to  find the exact type of map that the following is :

[image]

It looks like a hill-shaded topographic map, most likely DEM, but I'm not sure. I need to know for certain so i can contact the map provider and order this exact style, for use in my projects.

EDIT: After some research, I am wondering if anyone knows were to purchase this exact type of map. I have looked into the opencyclemap, but that map is not this 3-d nature, and my client is very keen on getting this 3-D effect. Once again, the "must be available offline" restriction is the biggest problem for me here.

I have looked into a program called Google Maps Terrain Downloader, and I am wondering if anyone has had any experience with using it. The program downloads "small tiles", so I`m concerned that it may not be able to help me with rendering most of the country.

Comment: That is the Google Maps terrain map. What is the problem providing it to your map provider as an example?

Comment: I need to get this exact type of map, but be able to use it completely offline( editing can be done online). I  wanted to know the name, as I will look into other ways to acquire this type of file before needing to pay

Comment: Yes, it is Google Terrain. If you need offline interactive/editing, you could either put together your own dataset, or look into other providers, such as enterprise solutions by MapBox (https://www.mapbox.com/enterprise/). Note: I have no affiliation with MapBox, there are probably other similar solutions, that is just one I am familiar with.

Comment: OpenCycleMap has Terrain for Slovakia  http://www.opencyclemap.org/?zoom=12&lat=52.9151050025&lon=-4.10991579681&layers=B00 can be used offline for no cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a small-to-medium–scale topographic map, with relief (or hill) shading but no elevation contours. The hill-shading is likely to have been based upon a DEM (digital elevation model) but you should not call the map itself a DEM.

Numerous other images of topo maps: [google image search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=topographic%20map&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=WlrIVLeFGsKPsQSDjILwCA&ved=0CEcQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=758)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, definitely familiarize yourself with the concept of map tiles, and you can investigate GMapCatcher or other downloaders, sounds like you already found one.

The concept of tiles is actually everywhere these days, its how browsable online maps like this are served up, our SAR group uses a huge offline repository of tiles on various map layers, and a simple offline java servlet to host them on a local web page.

When the tiles are downloaded into the correct specific directory structure, all the web page that views them has to do is grab tiles and display them in the right sequence.

When you say 'offline editing', do you mean that you want to be able to draw data and overlay it on this base map, or that you want to be able to edit the base map itself?

Comment: As mentioned, the editing can be done online, but the end product has to be available offline( it will be in a stationary place with no internet). I just need to create polygons on top of the base map, and the polygons should ideally match the basemap.

Comment: for android, take a look at locusmap.eu - but you're probably talking PC?  I think gmapcatcher does let you draw shapes overlaying the downloaded map tiles.